# Having Trouble with a cross Domain jquery/Ajax service call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, wcf

I've read through thread after thread on here and elsewhere trying to get a cross domain ajax call to work. I have a Restful WCF service that returns a simple bool. I have it setup with the proper response format (Json) and the expected url with the callback parameter:

```
[WebGet(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
UriTemplate = "ShowCreditCardTextJQUERY?memberNumber={memberNumber}&callback={callback}", 
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
```

My Ajax looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://example.com/service/service.svc/ShowTextJQUERY",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp",               
    crossDomain:true,
    data: "{'memberNumber':'" + memberNumber + "'}",
    cache: false,               
    //success: alert(memberNumber),
    success: function (data) {
        var output = data;

        if (!data) {
            $("#dialog").dialog(
           {
               modal: true,
               width: 735,
               height: 550
           });
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
    }
});
```

I receive a 200 for the response but that is coming in the error block. I am at a loss (and still pretty new to jquery/ajax). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Given the 200 response but no data it sounds like you're being stopped by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). If you check the console you can confirm this; there's will be an error about the receiving domain having no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. Have you enabled CORS on the WCF service?

Comment: I have not, how do I set that up?

Comment: Using the developer tools in IE I do see the response I expect coming back in the response body (in this case a bool value of false) if I change the datatype to json instead of jsonp it works fine on my localhost (obviously)

Comment: JSON and JSONP are not interchangeable - you need to return data in JSONP format for it to work. Also, if you are getting the error message I mentioned in the first comment, do a google for 'WCF enable CORS' and you should get a solution

Comment: Thanks, Don't see that error being returned, I see the value I am expecting. So maybe it's just an issue parsing the response.

Answer (score 0):

May be these lines of code solve your problem, which is for regular web service call

```
          var jsonData = [YOUR JSON PARAMETER];

            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                type: "POST",
                url: [YOUR WEB SERVICE URL],
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                  
                data: JSON.stringify({ json: jsonData }),
                dataType: "json",                
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function(err) {
                    alert("Error : " + err.d);
                }  
            }); 

            function OnSuccess(data) {
                alert("Success:" + data.d);                       
            }
```

You can do one thing for that just need to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin & Access-Control-Allow-Headers in CustomeHeaders your web service web.config file.

```
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
```

If you want to allow only for specific domain , you can do that with specific value of domain instead of * value